# How to save weights in tensorflow federated

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I want to save weights only when loss is getting lower and reuse them for evaluation.

```
lowest_loss = Inf

    if loss[round] < lowest_loss:
        lowest_loss = loss[round]

        model_weights = transfer_learning_iterative_process.get_model_weights(state)



eval_metric = federated_eval(model_weights, [fed_valid_data])
```

where:

```
  federated_eval = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_fn)
```

Is there a possible way to save server weights in hdf5 format or as a checkpoint and reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with helpers in TFF. Generally, this kind of functionality is implemented by [`tff.program.ProgramStateManagers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/program/ProgramStateManager). An implementation which saves to a filesystem can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/program/FileProgramStateManager), and example usages can be found in the implementation of [`tff.simulation.run_training_process`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.28.0/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/training_loop.py#L68-L185).